# what happens if I disable heap trimming completely?

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, system

I have an application which runs for a long period of time and allocates/deallocates small chunk of memory frequently. After some time I have noticed the application starts degrading in terms of performance.

I suspect that it is because of the memory sbrk is trying to release back to the system. If I use M_TRIM_THRESHOLD and set it to -1 using a mallopt call in my application then would it help in having better performance?

Will there be any side effects to setting this parameter? like more malloc failures?

Comment: You'll need to benchmark to get a definitive answer.

Comment: What OS?  What `[g]libc` version?  What you are asking is not standardized and any answer may be very platform-specific.

Comment: *I suspect that it is because of the memory sbrk is trying to release back to the system.*  Also, you don't need to suspect anything.  You can and probably should check this assumption with something like `strace` to see if the process actually is making those system calls.

Comment: *trying to release back to the system* sounds like a least suspicious reason for performance degradation. You should rather blame more obvious things such as algorithms (liner search through a list that gets longer?) or memory fragmentation.

Comment: I'm using a centos 7 with glibc version 2.17. Thanks for the pointer @AndrewHenle I'll try using strace.

Comment: If it only does an allocation "every now and then", then `sbrk` calls arecnot the cause of the slowdown. (Particularly if you never free the memory you allocate.)

Comment: @rici good point! I've modified text of the question to make it clear.